# Create GitHub repo under a different username?

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository

I've a personal GitHub account. I want to create a new repo but I don't want it to be under my personal namespace.

I want the new repo namespace to be something like `github.com/something-else/repo`. Then I want my personal account to be a contributor to that new repo.

Is this possible or do I have to create a new Github account just to get a new project "namespace"?

Comment: Does `something-else` exist yet? Is it (or do you intend for it to be) a user, or an organization?

Comment: @Chris It doesn't exist yet. Well I just want a new namespace that I and others can contribute to. So I guess it's an "organization"? But really it's just me for now.

Comment: In that case, yes, you need to create a user or organization with that name. GitHub doesn't really do "namespaces" unless you count users and organizations. I can add an answer now that we're clear on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub doesn't really have a concept of "namespaces" separate from users and organizations. If you want a place to put repositories apart from your personal account you'll need to create a new user or organization named `something-else` to hold those repositories.

Based on your description of

> a new namespace that I and others can contribute to

it sounds like an organization is a better fit. You can [create an organization while logged in with your existing user](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-new-organization-from-scratch/).

Comment: By creating a new organization, I don't necessarily need to create a new account right? Cause now I see in the Github tabs that there's a `+ New organization` link. So while I'm logged in my personal account, I just click that? Or do I have to logout and make new account as an organization?

Comment: @IMB, that's correct. To create an organization you must already have a user (your existing user will work fine). I've added a link to the official documentation in my answer.